# Добавление товара в корзину и удаление

Tags: php

Я сделал добавление товара в корзину и удаление, но если удалять товар, то удаляться будет всегда первый, как сделать, что бы удалить тот, который нужно?

```
<?php
abstract class Product{
    public $title;
    public $price;

    public function __construct($title, $price){
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->price = $price;
    }
}

class Cart{
    public $countPdoduct = [];

    public function getProduct($product){
        $addProduct = '';

        $addProduct = array_push($this->countPdoduct, $product);

        if($addProduct){
            echo 'Товар добавлен в корзину';
        }
    }

    public function deleteProduct($product){
        if(in_array($product, $this->countPdoduct)){
            unset($this->countPdoduct[0]);
            echo 'Товар удалён из корзины';
        }
    }

}

class Planshet extends Product{}

$planshet = new Planshet('Asus', 2000);

$korzina = new Cart();

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($korzina->countPdoduct);
echo '</pre>';


$korzina->getProduct($planshet); //добавляю товар в корзину

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($korzina->countPdoduct);
echo '</pre>';

$korzina->deleteProduct($planshet); //удаляю из корзины

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($korzina->countPdoduct);
```

Comment: `unset($this->countPdoduct[0]);` вы от этой строки ожидаете другого поведения? найдите индекс нужного элемента, и удалите нужный.

Comment: Сделал изменения, совпадения есть, но почему не удаляет? https://pastebin.com/FTxG7JVL

Comment: я боюсь вы не очень понимаете, что пишете, усугубляя все это опечатками в именах переменных. что по вашему делает функция `key` ?

Comment: возможно, вам поможет `unset($this->countPdoduct[$product->title])`.

Comment: я исправил опечатки и сделал, цикл foreacch и должен подставляться ключ, который надо удалить, но почему-то не удаляется, хотя значения выводит https://pastebin.com/971XasvU

Comment: обратите внимание на мой комментарий выше, у вас ключом массива `$countProduct` является названяи продуктов `$product->title`. Там в принципе не надо искать позицию, просто удалить по ключу (заголовку). Меня, правда, инетересно, как при такой реализации вы собираетесь добавлять по несоклько одинвуовых продуктов в корзину.

Comment: кстати, если убрать условие, то в цикле заработает удаление, только удалит всё

Comment: Я понял, то, что in_array ищет только значения, без ключей, то есть ключи она игнорирует

Comment: я другого способа не знаю

Comment: https://pastebin.com/uiWg8Psd

Comment: У меня получилось https://pastebin.com/UA2x2qAQ

Comment: `getProduct` - не может добавлять в карзину. `get` - взять, получить. а вот `addProduct` может.

Comment: то есть просто переименовать?

Comment: @DivMan Именно. `if($addProduct){` - лишнее, в массив запись всегда добавится. Думаю надо проверить если товар в карзине то увеличить количество.

Comment: я сделал свойство для счётчика, если добавить такой же товар то количество увеличивается https://pastebin.com/XHBymFhe

Comment: @DivMan Вы свой код неспеша почитайте. Он у вас непонятно что делает. Вы его тестировали? У продукта нету количества, есть только название и цена. В корзине есть количество каждого продукта. Json пример того как надо организовать данные https://pastebin.com/W34qbJqZ

Comment: $numberProduct это количество

Comment: Я переделал, и теперь количество товаров нормально считает, а вот цену не правильно, если добавить 4 одинаковых товара, 

стоимостью 2000, то должно получится 8000, а получается 16 000, почему? 

И почему не узнаётся цена добавленного товара?

Я же говорю ей, возьми общую цену у товаров, которые лежат в корзине и добавь к ним цену нового товара, а получается, 

что складывается общая цена и общая цена. https://pastebin.com/pJ8Ec1sL

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57428/discussion-between-e-p-and-divman).

Answer (score 0):

Правильный(или очень близко) вариант:

```
<?php

abstract class Product
{
    public function __construct($title, $price)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->price = $price;
    }

    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    protected $title;
    protected $price;
}

class Tablet extends Product {}

class Cart
{
    public function getItems()
    {
        return $this->items;
    }

    public function addItem(Product $product, $quantity = 1)
    {
        $key = $this->createProductKey($product);
        if ($this->productExists($product)) {
            $this->items[$key]["quantity"] += $quantity;
        } else {
            $this->items[$key] = ["quantity" => $quantity, "product" => $product];
        }
    }

    public function deleteItem(Product $product, $quantity = 1)
    {
        $key = $this->createProductKey($product);
        if ($this->productExists($product)) {
            $this->items[$key]["quantity"] -= $quantity;

            if ($this->items[$key]["quantity"] < 1) {
                unset($this->items[$key]);
            }
        }
    }

    public function getTotal()
    {
        $total = 0;
        foreach ($this->items as $key => $item) {
            $total += $item["quantity"] * $item["product"]->getPrice(); 
        }

        return $total;
    }

    protected function productExists(Product $product)
    {
        $key = $this->createProductKey($product);
        return array_key_exists($key, $this->items);
    }

    protected function createProductKey(Product $product)
    {
        return $product->getTitle() . '_' . $product->getPrice();
    }

    protected $items = [];
}


// Test data
$tablet1 = new Tablet("Asus 1", 100);
$tablet2 = new Tablet("Asus 2", 200);

$cart = new Cart();

$cart->addItem($tablet1);
$cart->addItem($tablet2);
$cart->addItem($tablet1, 10);

var_dump($cart->getItems());
var_dump($cart->getTotal());

$cart->deleteItem($tablet1, 2);
var_dump($cart->getItems());
var_dump($cart->getTotal());

$cart->deleteItem($tablet2);
var_dump($cart->getItems());
var_dump($cart->getTotal());
```