# Обращение к свойствам переданного объекта

Tags: php

Вот такая проблема, количество товаров нормально считает, а вот цену не правильно, если добавить 4 одинаковых товара, стоимостью 2000, то должно получится 8000, а получается 16 000, почему?

И почему не узнаётся цена добавленного товара?

Я же говорю ей, возьми общую цену у товаров, которые лежат в корзине и добавь к ним цену нового товара, а получается, что складывается общая цена и общая цена.

```
<?php

abstract class Product{
    public $title;
    public $price;
    public $numberProduct;

    public function __construct($title, $price, $numberProduct = 1){
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->price = $price;
        $this->numberProduct = $numberProduct;
    }
}

class Cart{
    public $countProduct = [];

    public function addProduct($product){

    if(array_key_exists($product->title, $this->countProduct)){ //если такой товар уже есть в корзине
                                                                    //то его количество учеличить на 1
        $this->countProduct[$product->title]->numberProduct++;

        $this->countProduct[$product->title]->price += $product->price;
        var_dump($product->price);

        echo 'Товар добавлен в корзину<br>';
        echo 'Количество ' . $product->numberProduct . '<br>';
        echo 'Цена ' . $this->countProduct[$product->title]->price . '<br>';
        echo '<br>';
        }

        else{ //если нету, то добавить
            $this->countProduct[$product->title] = $product;
            echo 'Товар добавлен в корзину<br>';
            echo '<br>';
        }
    }
}

class Planshet extends Product{}

$asus = new Planshet('Asus', 2000);

$korzina = new Cart();

$korzina->addProduct($asus); //добавляю товар в корзину
$korzina->addProduct($asus); //добавляю товар в корзину
$korzina->addProduct($asus); //добавляю товар в корзину
$korzina->addProduct($asus); //добавляю товар в корзину
```

Comment: Правильно, ты же не создал 4 разных товара `Planshet`, а один и тот же добавляешь.... вот он цену сам у себя и прибавляет постоянно... 0+2 =2...2+2=4... 4+4=8... 8+8=16........... а numberProduct явно нужно не по title определять...

Comment: Зачем мне разные? Я хочу купить несколько одинаковых товаров, каждый товар по 2000, хочу взять 4, значит должно быть 8 000, а тут совсем почему-то всё не так.

Comment: Когда ты в магазине покупаешь 4 планшета, ты покупаешь 4 планшета, а не один и тот же 4 раза ......... (фактически это разные товары, хотя и производитель один)

Comment: Я вообще еще не знаю, зачем в продукте есть поле `$numberProduct` ..... оно к продукту вообще не должно относиться... товар же считается в корзине... вот там все эти подсчеты и должны вестись....

Comment: Ну вот теперь я создал разные объекты и суммируется нормально, но почему, если узнать сумму у первого объекта, то к нему прибавляется сумма у всех товаров? Как сделать, что бы оставалась изначальная? https://pastebin.com/v4KCDW4C

Comment: А как тогда мне ввести подсчёт одинаковых товаров?

Comment: Не складывайте цену. Просто **при выводе** умножьте цену на количество.

Comment: Я убрал поле numberProduct, вы такое имели ввиду? https://pastebin.com/3XPKhDYJ

Comment: А зачем плодить вопросы?
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/655711/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Добавление товара в корзину и удаление](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/655711/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b7%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Comment: На самом деле вопрос довольно большой... я бы на данный момент порекомендовал пойти на какой-нибудь гитхаб и посмотреть парочку реализаций и попробовать понять что там происходит и почему...... типа https://github.com/mike182uk/cart/blob/master/src/Cart.php   ...... https://github.com/seikan/cart.class.php/blob/master/cart.class.php  ... и что-то типа такого

Answer (score 1):

`Ну вот теперь я создал разные объекты и суммируется нормально, но почему, если узнать сумму у первого объекта, то к нему прибавляется сумма у всех товаров? Как сделать, что бы оставалась изначальная`

Все очень просто. Объекты в php передаются по ссылке. Из-за этой строчки

```
$this->countProduct[$product->title]->price += $product->price;
```

вы каждый раз удваиваете цену в объекте $asus. Для проверки напишите

```
$korzina->addProduct($asus); //добавляю товар в корзину
var_dump($asus);
$korzina->addProduct($asus); //добавляю товар в корзину
var_dump($asus);
$korzina->addProduct($asus); //добавляю товар в корзину
var_dump($asus);
$korzina->addProduct($asus); //добавляю товар в корзину
var_dump($asus);
```

И вы увидите что вашего товара цена увеличивается.
В корзине нужно хранить ссылку на объект и количество этих товаров, чтобы потом посчитать общую стоимость корзины.